# Assinging numeric number to rows and after delation come back to proper order

Tags: php, jquery

I have some issues with my code:

- first is row assigning number. It does not assign the numeric number
  to first row
- secondly how to pre-assign the `Discount` to `0` and it can be editable if I want to change.

The images of my problems are attached below.

- Doesn't assign the numeric number to first row

[image: Doesnt aasinging the numeric number to first row]

[image: Doesnt aasinging the numeric number to first row]

- On delete some row it doesn't automatically , in a proper numeric order e.g on deleting `2` & `4` it does not come back to `1`, `2`, `3`

[image: Disorder Issue]

My jquery code is
a

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#data').DataTable( {
            "scrollY":        "460px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging":        true
        } );
    } );



        $(function(){
            $('body').delegate('.discount,.quantity,.price','keyup',function(){
                var tr      =   $(this).parent().parent();  
                var dis     =   tr.find('.discount').val();
                var qty     =   tr.find('.quantity').val();
                var price   =   tr.find('.price').val();
                var total   =   (qty*price) -(dis);
                tr.find('.amount').val(total);
                totals();
            });

        $('.pay').change(function(){
            var pay      =  $(this).val()-0;
            var subtoal  =  $('.subtotal').val()-0;
            $('.payback').val(pay-subtoal);
        }); 

        $('.datavalue').click(function(){
            var id      =$(this).data('id');
            var name    =$(this).data('name');
            var price   =$(this).data('price');
            addrow(id,name,price);
        });

        $('body').delegate('.remove','click',function(){
            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            tr.remove();
            totals();
        });
    }); 
        function addrow(id,p,p2)
    {
    $('.count').each(function(idx){
    $("td:first", this).html(idx+1);
});
    var tr = '<tr class= count>'+
                '<td></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" value=" '+ p +' " class="form-control product_name"><input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value=" '+ id +' " class="form-control product_name"></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="form-control quantity"></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" value=" '+ p2 +' " class="form-control price"></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="discount[]" class="form-control discount"></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount"></td>'+
                '<td><a href="#" class="remove">Del</a></td>'+
            '</tr>';

            $('.details').append(tr);

    }   

    function totals()
        {
            var tt = 0;
            $('.amount').each(function(e,i){
                var amt = $(this).val()-0;
                tt +=  amt;
            });
            $('.subtotal').val(tt);
        }


          function OpenPopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
                var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
                var top = (screen.height - h) / 4;  // for 25% - devide by 4  |  for 33% - devide by 3
                var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
            } 

    </script>
```

Comment: Tried to fix your language, but it's still really hard to understand, like what is a "numeric number" -- do you mean sequential?

Comment: @JamesZ numeric number means that 1-2-3-4-5-6....

Answer (score 0):

To number your rows, you can use [jQuery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('tr').each(function(row_number) {
   $(this).find('td').first().text(row_number + 1);
});
```

Call this when you add or delete a row and it will correct your problem.

Comment: Still facing the same issue .... `$('.count').each(function(idx){
    $("td:first", this).html(idx+1);` I already mention this using in my above code ... do you have some alternative way ?

Comment: It looks like your add row is doing the count, and then adding a new row, so that won't have the idx assigned. Add your row first, and then number them. Perhaps you can use https://jsfiddle.net/ to setup an example?

Comment: Sorry, you code just doesn't work as I can't see how to add or remove rows. You are asking for more than your original question about numbering

Comment: i dont think so , i put three questions , nd 2 is about numbering :/

Comment: But the code you posted doesn't even work to display the screenshots you posted. To pre-assign the discount to be 0, just add `data-value="0"` or `<input value="0" />`. The field is editable unless you add `disabled="disabled"` property.

Comment: will you give me one favour ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157722/discussion-between-alex-holsgrove-and-newbiee).